# How do I remove akamai and speed up my iMac?

Tags: imac, performance, leopard

I have an iMac (running Leopard) going deadly slow, I discarded any hardware problems (Hardware tests, disk utility, etc..)  and the only strange thing I've found is a folder called 'akamai'

After searching on the web, apparently it's not a bug aor virus, it's just a download manager but for some reason, in some cases it seems it doesn't install properly and creates an error that provokes this problems (I'm not sure but I think it's because it is copying some log on an infinite loop or something similar)

See the following post on Apple support pages:
https://discussions.apple.com/message/17622495#17622495
So aparently there is many people having problems with this, I'm not sure if this is causing mine as well but the question is that there is no way to remove that folder. How can I know if this folder is slowing my Mac?

Comment: Can you add some more details to make it easier to understand what you are looking at solving here? It would also help if you add some information about how this is Apple related.

Comment: @patrix akamai is an additional downloaded that some nasty apps (MS and Adobe) make you add to download see <http://www.akamai.com/client> and the web page does not have a secure certificate. (and the uninstall directions give the wrong directory - I think uninstalling  is definitely called for here)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, the problem though is exactly that it doesn't let you remove it, that is actually my question, how to remove it / uninstall it,